# Explanation for dark states in magneto-optical trap pumping the $\mathrm{^{85}Rb}$ $F=3 \rightarrow F'=4$ transition

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, laser

The explanation given by Wikipedia on why you will find the $\mathrm{^{85}Rb}$ atoms going into the $F=2$ hyperfine state (and thus needing repumping) is that the detuning from the $F=3 \rightarrow F'=4$ transition will allow some small, but nonzero, overlap with the $F=3 \rightarrow F'=3$ transition. I have a few questions regarding this:

1. How you would calculate the probability of driving the $F=3 \rightarrow F'=3$ transition versus the $F=3 \rightarrow F'=4$ transition?
2. Does this overlap arise from the bandwidth of the laser, or the natural linewidth of the transitions (or something else)?
3. <strike>Selection rules tell us that the $F'=4 \rightarrow F'=3$ transition is allowed; can this transition happen if the atoms in the gas cell collide with the container and lose energy? If so, how frequent is this event compared to the $F=3 \rightarrow F'=3$ transition?</strike> I think this question doesn't make sense, because A) our gas's temperature should be much lower than the walls, so it will probably gain energy upon colliding , and B) if we are trapping it in the center then it should not collide with the walls anyway.

I'm sure a lot of this will depend on some details of your system (such as number density of the rubidium atoms), but assumptions can be made about those details to answer for an example system if needed.